# Calculate number of days between two dates in Perl

Tags: perl, datetime

I am using Perl to create a script that will email password expiration notifications.

I have two dates:

1. The date that the users password was set
2. The date that the users password will expire (180 days after the password was set)

   ```
   use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

   my $dt_pattern      = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new( pattern => '%F',);
   my $displayName = $entry->get_value("displayName");

   my $pwdLastSet = convertWinFileTimestamp($entry->get_value("pwdLastSet"));

   # Determine password expiration date
   my $pwdLastSet_dt = $dt_pattern->parse_datetime($pwdLastSet);
   my $pwdExpirationDate = $pwdLastSet_dt->add( days => $maxPwdAge );

   # Days until password expires
   # HELP!!!!!!!

   sub convertWinFileTimestamp {
           my $timestamp = shift;
           # Strip off nanoseconds, then adjust date from AD epoch (1601) to UNIX epoch (1970)
           return POSIX::strftime( "%Y-%m-%d",
           localtime( ( $timestamp / 10000000 ) - 11644473600 ) );
   }
   ```

I cannot figure out how to calculate the difference between the two dates!

Below is the output for each variable:

```
    pwdLastSet:     2015-02-12
    pwdExpireDate:  2015-08-11T00:00:00
```

Any help much appreciated...been googling like crazy but I can't figure it out...Thanks!

I tried the following lines of code:

```
    my $pwdDaysLeft = int(($pwdExpirationDate - $pwdLastSet) / 86400);
```

but got the following error:

```
    Only a DateTime::Duration or DateTime object can  be subtracted from a DateTime object. at pwdreminder.pl line 65
```

Comment: Googling for the title of your question brings this: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=17057 as the first result. Please explain how it does not work for you?

Comment: I get the following error when I add the following line of code: my $pwdDaysLeft = int(($pwdExpirationDate - $pwdLastSet) / 86400); "Only a DateTime::Duration or DateTime object can  be subtracted from a DateTime object. at pwdreminder.pl line 65"

Comment: What is `convertWinFileTimestamp`? And presumably `$maxPwdAge` is 180? By `pwdExpireDate`, do you mean `$pwdExpirationDate`? It is best to show a self-contained piece of code that we can run for ourselves.

Comment: Why do you declare and assign to `$pwdLastSet_dt` twice?

Comment: convertWinFileTimestamp is a subroutine that converts the windows time stamp to something that perl can read. Sorry the pwdLastSet_dt was copied into the forum twice, I will fix it

Comment: Also I added the sub routine code to the question

Comment: So the question becomes: "How do I get DateTime from a Windows timestamp?"

Comment: So I think what you're saying is my time variables are in two different time formats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, we have three dates here:

- The date that the password was last set. This starts off as a string in the format `YYYY-MM-DD` stored in `$pwdLastSet`, but then you parse it into a DateTime object stored in `$pwdLastSet_dt`.
- The date that the current password expires. This is calculated by adding `$maxPwdAge` days to `$pwdLastSet_dt`, which gives a DateTime object which is then stored in `$pwdExpirationDate`.
- The current date. Which, in your current code, you don't calculate.

What you actually want is the difference in days a between the second and third of these two dates. We can ignore the first date as is it only used to calculate the second date. I assume that you're calculating that correctly.

Hopefully, the password expiration date will always be in the future. So the calculation we want to do is:

```
my $diff = $pwdExpirationDate - $current_date;
```

As long as both of those are DateTime objects, we'll get a DateTime::Duration object back, which we can then ask for the number of days.

DateTime has a `today()` method that will give the current date. So our code becomes:

```
# Use delta_days() to get a duration object that just contains days
my $diff = $pwdExpirationDate->delta_days(DateTime->today);
print $diff->in_units('days');
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much!